# Pagination by geometry distance using a cursor

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as this (I am using MySQL 8.0):

```sql
create table `studio` (
    `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    `position` point srid 4326 not null
) default character set utf8mb4 engine = InnoDB;
```

Now I am triying to paginate by geometry distance using a cursor, but none of the methods I can think of seems very efficient.

Using `having` (cursor: { distance: 5502111.294724894, id: 24 }):

```sql
select *,
  ST_Distance_Sphere(e0.position, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
    '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[42.605556,-5.57]}', 1, 4326)
  ) as distance
from `studio` as `e0`
having (distance >= 5502111.294724894 and (distance > 5502111.294724894 or id < 24))
order by `distance` asc, `e0`.`id` desc limit 6
```

Using `where` (cursor: { distance: 5502111.294724894, id: 24 }):

```sql
select *,
  ST_Distance_Sphere(e0.position, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
    '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[42.605556,-5.57]}', 1, 4326)
  ) as distance
from `studio` as `e0`
where (
  ST_Distance_Sphere(e0.position, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
    '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[42.605556,-5.57]}', 1, 4326)
  ) >= 5502111.294724894
) and (
  ST_Distance_Sphere(e0.position, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
    '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[42.605556,-5.57]}', 1, 4326)
  ) > 5502111.294724894 
  or id < 24
)
order by `distance` asc, `e0`.`id` desc limit 6
```

I too tried using a "user-defined variable", but this don't work correctly. I don't sure if this method is possible, I never used a "user-defined variable" before (cursor: { distance: 5502111.294724894, id: 24 }):

```sql
select *,
  @distance := ST_Distance_Sphere(e0.position, ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
    '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[42.605556,-5.57]}', 1, 4326)
  ) as distance
from `studio` as `e0`
where (@distance >= 5502111.294724894) and (@distance > 5502111.294724894 or id < 24)
order by `distance` asc, `e0`.`id` desc limit 6
```

I have few experience with SQL, so my questions are:

- Am I forgetting any possible method that works better or more efficiently?
- Which of the above solutions is better or more efficient?
- Can the last method be valid? What could be failing with it?

Comment: Did you find something? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, I didn't find anything. Finally I chose to use `having`.